# Getting into a meditative mindset for yoga

Tags: yoga

I've done yoga several times, but am not really big into it.  I'd like to get more into it.  The problem is, I'm the type whose mind is always running.  Trying to simply stop and feel my inner self, or feel the posture, or whatever seems very hard.  Is this something someone picks up as they progress, or is there a trick to it?

Comment: Voting to reopen because I feel that it is viable to get an answer to this.

Comment: Agree to opening.

Comment: Yoga classes typically starts with meditative exercises like pranayama which purpose partially is to prepare the mind for Asana practice.

Answer (score 2):

Concentration on your breathing during any posture is one of the primary thing you can start with. Bring your mind on your body part(s) where you feel more stretch (or pain at initial time) during any yoga posture. ie. observing the posture along with normal breathing.
Over the period of time (3 to 6 months ), gradually you will feel that your mind will be coming under your control